# How to format table columns alignment in Reports Template based on Ad Hoc view (crosstabs, tables) In JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm just wondering is it possible to format columns alignment in Jaspersoft Server Report, based on Ad Hoc view ? By default columns are on the left side, and if Report contains only several columns it looks a bit weird. I have added some header and footer to the Templates in the Studio, so we have a logo and some variables due to the client's requirements, but I can't find how to centralize columns when I run the Report on Server ?! Google it for past couple of days, but still can't find the solution. Tried to modify Source by adding some styles, but without success ... Any ideas where to look ? Thanks

P.S. Here is a sample what I want to achieve -->
[image]

Comment: P.S. We using 6.0.1 Pro Version.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your current situation, with indications how you like it?...

Comment: Yes, sure. How you can see from the screenshot, Report has only 3 columns, and by default I believe, its alignment set to the left. But I want them to be centrelized. There is no any Formatting buttons when you creating the Ad Hoc view, also I've tried modify Template within the Studio, but no success yet ... Thank you

Comment: Particular this Report was made with the Letterportrait Template, but it even worse looking when I choose a Landscape Template ...

Comment: Thanks, if its html I would try with the net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class property and then download a css to the server.. that align your table to the center..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you provide some guidline where to find that class and export it ? To change the theme and login page I modified the overwrite.css file and uploaded to the server, but have no idea where to look for the net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class ??! Thanks

Comment: The  net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class is a property that you can add with in the jrxml to any reportElement <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="TEST"/>, i don't have a precis solution for you but if you try to add this property, checking the html, i guess that some way you can find a solution with css. To answer I need to see the html generated and the jrxml

Comment: Unfortunatelly cannot provide you with the html or jrxml files due to the company policy. But will try the solution you suggested. Will let you know the outcome. Thank you anyways for your reply!